# Convert milliseconds to time in extjs or javascript

Tags: javascript, extjs, time

Is there a built in method in extjs or javascript for converting milliseconds to a time?

I found one for date, but it doesn't work.  I always get Jan, 1 1970 08:00 (Pacific Standard Time).  When I try test.getHours I get 0. I am trying to print out 8:00 or 08:00

```
  var getSignOnRecord = 28800000;
  var test = new Date(getSignOnRecord);
  test.getHours() // 0 ???? Should be 8
```

Comment: @dandavis, this keeps returning 12:00 AM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use ISOString date formats for up to 24 hours of time:

```
new Date(28800000).toISOString().split("T")[1].split(".")[0]; // == "08:00:00"
```

you can easily slice() the remaining text to eliminate seconds or whatnot.

this works because using a "unix" stamp results in an GMT offset, and ISO also displays GMT, so by throwing away the date part, you're left with a pretty readable format of up to 23h59m59s...

Comment: I don't think it's a formatting question, it's why the OP is not getting 8 for the hours

Comment: @JuanMendes: OP said "I am trying to print out 8:00 or 08:00". he also had a timezoneOffset to contend with, so i think it's both issues working against him... I like using ISOString to avoid having to shift offsets and get the pretty formatting all in one.

Comment: Thanks, how would I split seconds off, I have been trying to 20 minutes and have had not luck

Comment: `new Date(28800000).toISOString().split("T")[1].split(".")[0].slice(0, -3)=="08:00"`

Comment: @dandavis The main question is the `getHours/getUTCHours`, I don't think the OP would have a problem had they been using `getUTCHours`, even if they did, questions at StackOverflow are supposed to be about a single problem.

Answer (score 3):

You are getting the localized hour, but you want the hours at UTC

```
new Date(28800000).getUTCHours() // 8
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getHours

> The getHours() method returns the hour for the specified date, according to local time.

Comment: the title is asking for ms to be converted to a time, not just hours. The code in the OP is just the first part of the title's problem. Using `getUTCHours()` is not a bad solution to part of it, which is why i recommended it on a comment on Ilya's answer before you posted it as a full answer. Due to feedback in removed answers, i realized the need to do the whole time, and posted an example of the nice ms to h:m:s:ms formatting js provides via toISOStrings. if one needed to hand-build those time pieces, getUTCHours() is an integral part and this answer demonstrates that quite well.

Answer (score 1):

`new Date(value);`

`value`: Integer value representing the number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC

28800000 ms is indeed 1 January 1970, 8h

> When I try test.getHours I get 0

NB `value` is UTC, `getHours` is local time

Comment: Right, but when I try value.getHours() I get 0 instead of 8

Comment: getHours is localTime, what is your time zone ?

Comment: ahh, use `date.getUTCHours()`

Answer (score 0):

This is a math problem. As far as I know, there is no function that does this in native JavaScript, but can be coded from scratch.

```
function convertToTime(milliseconds) {
    var seconds = Math.floor(milliseconds / 1000) % 60
    var minutes = Math.floor(milliseconds / (1000 * 60)) % 60
    var hours = Math.floor(milliseconds / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24

    return (hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours) + ":" + 
           (minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes) + ":" + 
           (seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds :seconds);   
}
```

There's also probably a method like this in `momentjs`.

Comment: Please put some `var`s in there, but what do you mean JavaScript doesn't do it natively? It doesn't format it, but it definitely creates Dates from milliseconds.